# New programmer, need help. Assigning a field inherited from superclass to a variable inside a subclass' method

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I want to assign the basePrice (which is inherited field from Hamburger class) to the double newPrice variable inside the overwritten addItems() method. This was not a problem in the super class since the field existed. I just typed "double newPrice = this.basePrice;". But, this is not working in the subclass. I'm new to programming, any help appreciated.

```
public class HealthyBurger extends Hamburger{

    public HealthyBurger(String meat, double basePrice) {
        super("Healthy Burger", "brown rye", meat, basePrice);
    }

    public void addItems() {
        double newPrice = ???HOW TO ASSISGN basePrice HERE???;
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends if `basePrice` is private, or if there is a setter method for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access `this.basePrice` from the derived class, `basePrice` attribute has to be `protected` in the base class.

Then you can do:

```
this.basePrice = ...; // whatever you want here
```

Comment: This really solved my problem, the course I'm watching still hasn't mentioned protected keyword thought I've seen it here and there. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is a method called `getBasePrice()` which you should invoke:

```
this.getBasePrice();
// instead of
this.basePrice;
```

If there isn't one, go to the source code of Hamburger (`Hamburger.java`) and add this method.

### Explanation

If you get an error when you write `this.basePrice` in your `HealthyBurger` class, that means the field in the `Hamburger` class is either marked as `private` or, it BOTH [1] is in another package, and [2] has been declared with no access modifier (which is java-ese for a concept called *package private* - meaning, only things inside the package can touch it, and you're not in there).

One fix is to go into the source code of `Hamburger.java` and make it `protected` instead (which means: Any source code in this file, all classes in the same package, and any subclasses - and that last one will open up the doors for you), but it is more idiomatic java to make fields private, so leave it as is, and make this method, which is called a 'getter', and should probably be `public`.

NB: If you find it tedious to write these, there's always [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a  `getBasePrice()` method defined in the parent class or just declare the field:

`protected double basePrice`

and you can just assign `double newPrice = this.basePrice;`

Comment: then what with `getBasePrice()` ?

Comment: @Pierre It has more sense to declare the field with protected modifier, but if he can't do this for some reason, he could create a getBasePrice() method for accessing the value of that instance